# how to mount seperate partition for /var

Tags: partitioning, mount, virtualbox, fstab

So i am trying to write a script for hardening Ubuntu based on CIS benchmarks,
this is what recommended for /var:[CIS benchmark details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCYaG.png)

for testing purpose i have installed a new Ubuntu 22.04 in Vbox,
`findmnt --kernel /var` has no output, so /var is not mounted.
My question is how do I mount /var as a separate partition, i have tried adding  `/dev/sda3 /var ext4 defaults 2 2` to the `/etc/fstab` file and run `mount -a` command to mount `/var` , this does not give any error and also shows in the list when i run `findmnt --kernel`, but when i reboot the system, the OS crashes.

Please help me in implementing this.

Comment: i tried the recommended method, theere its suggeted to create a seperate partition and then start with mounting, when i run ```sudo parted -l```  i only get ```/dev/sda``` partion and it will remove the OS if i partiton this for mounting /var @Raffa